# Forward Declaration in C

Tags: c

I wanted to ask about Forward Declarations in C. How generally they work. 
For example if in a file I declare

`struct task_struct;`

and define the struct in other file will it work? Because as far as I know Compiler must know the size of variable that is being declared. If it does then how does compiler actually handles such type of requests?

I found the above example in Linux Source code that got me interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you use a forward declaration, the *type* becomes ***Incomplete type*** for the compiler.
Compiler does not know anything about the size or layout of the type and hence you cannot perform any operation which needs the compiler to know these.

In C, If you forward declare a type, you can only use a pointer to that type. Since pointers to all structure types need same size<sup>[Note]</sup>, the compiler is just happy to know that it has a pointer to a type.

> **If I forward declare a structure and define it other file will it work?**

It will as long as you only use a pointer to the structure in the file which forward declares the structure. If you dereference the pointer you will get errors, Since compiler is not aware of the layout of the Incomplete type.

---

<sup>[Note]</sup> Thanks to melpomene & Daniel for this clarification.

Comment: "pointers to all types need same size" - this is wrong. Different pointer types can have different sizes. However, all *struct* pointers are guaranteed to have the same size.

Comment: @melpomene: The Q is tagged C and not C++?

Comment: I know. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @melpomene: Please provide me a citation from C standard which states pointers can have different sizes on the same platform & I will incorporate your objection.AFAIK, POSIX requires pointers to have the same size. Pointer to member functions in C++ can have varying sizes though.

Comment: Please provide me a citation from the C standard that states all pointers must have the same size. (ISO 9899:1999, 6.2.5/26: "[...] All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. [...] Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.")

Comment: @AlokSave POSIX may require all pointers to have the same size, but the C standard does not. The standard does however require that all pointers to `struct`s have the same representation and alignment requirements (similar for pointers to `union`s).

Comment: @melpomene: Thanks. same to you as well, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

What does "work" mean? Either way it will work in its own way.

At the point where the full declaration of struct type is not visible, it is an incomplete type and is usable as incomplete type only.

At the point where the full declaration of struct type is visible, it becomes a complete type and is usable as complete type.

That's all there is to it.

The usability of incomplete struct types is significantly reduced compared to complete ones. Basically, you can only declare pointers to such types and pass them around. Anything else (like declaring an object of that type) will require the full declaration.

Comment: My main meaning of work was that can I use this without getting a compile time error because I was not aware that this can be done.